# Can I continue to use Hibernate 3.0 when migrating PostgreSQL 8.2 to 9.2?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.2

I'm working on a project that uses Hibernate 3.0. The program was released around 2007 and is connected to a PosgreSQL 8.2 Database.

As we want to relaunch the project (thousands and thousands lines of code) I was asked to update the Database to 9.2 - which is crazy since the 8.3 PostgreSQL alone made a huge step forward.

My question now, does anyone have any experience with Hibernate 3.0 in connection with PostgreSQL 9.2? Will I need to upgrade hibernate? I know upgrading it to 3.6 will bring huge performance improvements. But looking at the migration guide and the amount of code, it will be a horror trip to upgrade hibernate version to version.

Thanks!

Comment: 8.3 is no longer supported, so you should upgrade as soon as possible

Comment: thank you, that is the reason why we want to update the database. the question is if it pays out to update hibernate as well nor not

Answer (score 1):

Actually, upgrading from 8.2 to 9.2 is not crazy at all.

The biggest challenge is 8.2 to 8.3, due the removal of implicit cast to `text` [per the 8.3.0 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-3.html).

In comparison the other compatibility-affecting changes, like the change of `bytea` to `hex` by default and `standard_conforming_strings` being `on` by default, are more minor and easily worked around by compatibility settings if necessary.

Since you have to do a dump and reload to get from 8.2 to any newer version (`pg_upgrade` only supports 8.4 and newer) you might as well go straight to 9.2.

I strongly recommend updating to the latest Hibernate 3.x release, as the Hibernate PostgreSQL dialect code will contain compatibility fixes for newer PostgreSQL releases, bug fixes, performance enhancements, etc. You might want to look and see what the oldest major release in the 3.x series has proper support for a recent PostgreSQL if you think it's going to be too hard to go all the way to 3.6.

A reasonable option would be to:

- Upgrade to the latest PgJDBC
- Do a test install of 9.2 and a dump and reload of your data onto it so you can use it as a test server
- Run a copy of your app against the 9.2 server, see if you have any issues with your current Hibernate release.
- Decide what to do from there, once you have data not just guesses.